# Broken python dependencies on an Ubuntu 16.04 (AWS EC2)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, dependencies, ubuntu-16.04

I attempted to remove all installed python on my Ubuntu 16.04 .As it stands, I now understand I should not have done that. However, just trying to reinstall python doesn't work.

When I try

```
$ sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,710 B of archives.
After this operation, 68.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) ...
# Empty sitecustomize.py to avoid a dangling symlink
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fc6b52dd700 (most recent call first):
Aborted
dpkg: error processing package python3.5-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5-minimal
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ python3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f87215c4700 (most recent call first):
Aborted
```

I tried installing some of the dependencies, I noticed were missing to no avail

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install python3.5-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.5-minimal is already the newest version (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Have tried different things but at this point I am lost as to how to go about this problem

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install dh-python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dh-python is already the newest version (2.20151103ubuntu1.1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with python3 after ubuntu upgrading from 16 to 18. But you can try to use my solve on 16. Just use  `apt-get` against `apt`

NOTE: I need python2.7 installed in my system.

I followed those steps:

1. Uninstall all python3 packages:

   `sudo apt remove python3 && sudo apt autoremove`
2. But this doesn`t help me. So will try to define which packages still exists in the system:

   `apt list --installed | grep python*`

   ```
   //possible output:
   WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
   libpython-stdlib/bionic,now 2.7.15~rc1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   libpython2.7-minimal/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   libpython2.7-stdlib/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   libpython3-stdlib/bionic-updates,now 3.6.7-1~18.04 amd64 [installed]
   libpython3.5/now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12 amd64 [installed,local]
   libpython3.5-minimal/now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12 amd64 [installed,local]
   libpython3.5-stdlib/now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12 amd64 [installed,local]
   libpython3.6/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   libpython3.6-minimal/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   libpython3.6-stdlib/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   python/bionic,now 2.7.15~rc1-1 amd64 [installed]
   python-apt-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,now 1.6.5ubuntu0.5 all [installed]
   python-minimal/bionic,now 2.7.15~rc1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   python2.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   python2.7-minimal/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   ```
3. As we can see, some of python3 packages are in the system. Will remove them.

   `sudo apt remove libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib`
4. Now, try to install python3

   `sudo apt install python3`
5. All should be OK

Comment: Finally after about an hour of trying to fix my problem. Your solution works fine for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a better idea to install python from a deb package with `sudo dpkg -i`? You can download it [from here](https://pkgs.org/download/python), for example

Comment: Hi thanks, please how can i grab that ? I'm working on a virtual server

Comment: Hi thanks, please how can i grab that ? I'm working on a virtual server

Comment: You can download files using `wget`. Direct links: [py2.7 (amd64)](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb), [py2.7 (i386)](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.11-1_i386.deb), [py3.5 (amd64)](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb), [py3.5 (i386)](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3_3.5.1-3_i386.deb)

Comment: Oh, by the way, it's for Ubuntu 16.04+. What os are you using?

Comment: Well yes i'm using 16.04. However having dowloaded it. I still get problems `$ sudo dpkg -i python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb
dpkg: regarding python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb containing python3, pre-dependency problem:
 python3 pre-depends on python3-minimal (= 3.5.1-3)
  python3-minimal is unpacked, but has never been configured.

dpkg: error processing archive python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing python3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb`

Comment: Maybe `sudo dpkg --configure -a` will help

Comment: I guess [this](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/base-images-docker/issues/146) is nearer to your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should try:
`sudo apt-get update`

Then try uninstalling python with below command

`sudo apt purge python3.x-minimal`

if it uninstall successfully then

`sudo apt-get install python3.6`

Comment: Hi, Thanks. So when i try to uninstall; `$ sudo apt purge python3.x-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.x-minimal
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.x-minimal'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.x-minimal'
`

Comment: @Austin - you need to replace the ".x " from  python3.x-minimal with your actual python version. For example if you want to remove python3.5 -> sudo apt purge python3.5-minimal.